# My function onClick its not working in mobile version (React.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some situations when I have onClick function in the mobile version it's not working(not clicking) when I try to open something or if I want to do something.

```
const items = [
    {
      key: "1",
      label: isPinned ? "Unpin panel" : "Pin panel",
      icon: (
        <FontAwesomeIcon
          icon={faThumbTack}
          className={
            isPinned ? styles.pinIconStyleClicked : styles.pinIconStyle
          }
        />
      ),
      onClick: () => handlePinned(),
    },
    moduleCapabilities &&
      moduleCapabilities.includes("cbFullscreen") && {
        key: "2",
        label: "Maximize panel",
        icon: (
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faExpand} className={styles.fullscreenStyle} />
        ),
        onClick: () => handleMaximize(),
      },
    {
      key: "3",
      label: "Remove panel",
      icon: (
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrashCan} className={styles.closeIconStyle} />
      ),
      onClick: () => {
        setVisibleDelPopconfirm(true);
      },
    },
  ];
```

How can I fixed this issue?
How can I do for large screen or small screen(mobile version)?

I tried with onTouchStrat etc...because I'm using `window.innderWidth`
to catch the size for the screen

- I used both onClick and onTouchStrat but I had the problem again.
- I used only onTouchStart or OnTouchEnd but when I have larg screen I want only clicked function